# Local Database for Silverlight, MonoTouch, MonoDroid, and Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a local database that will work with Silverlight, Windows Phone, MonoDroid, and MonoTouch.

My application is probably going to treat the database as read-only, but I don't want to have to re-encode the data for each platform. (I am also this close '...' to just using XML.)

Comment: XML could be a valid solution, but in my opinion you could have a watch to SQLite. You can use it in MT, MD and Windows-Phone and I think also in SL (but I'm not so sure).

Answer (score 5):

I used the Mono.Data.Sqlite libraries for the Mono for Android and MonoTouch versions of my app and use the [C# SQLite / Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite) libraries on the Windows Phone.

Not all the features are implemented with this version, but most are and it is useable.

I used a slightly modified version of the [sqlite-net](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/) library for a really basic ORM. sqlite-net uses P/Invoke which is not allowed on the Windows Phone, so I removed these and replaced it with the classes (eg: SqliteCommand) from the other libraries.

What is also nice is that they have the same method signatures so all I have to do is:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
    using Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient;
#else
    using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe sterling db would work, http://sterling.codeplex.com/.  It's worth checking out, it's simple yet powerfull.

Answer (score 0):

Db4objects seems like a great database. It works with Java and .NET (can be used with Win Phone). It has both GPL and Commercial License. It is an object database so no ORM, mapping etc will be needed.

http://www.db4o.com/